# Ruby on Rails 5.1 & Vue.js 2.4.x – Testing with Karma, Jasmine – How to install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, karma-jasmine

I have Rails 5.1.x and Vue.js 2.4.x; I do not mix Rails and Vue.js in the frontend – only Vue.js is used

I added the following packages:

*package.json*

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
...
```

**Q1**: Where do I do the configuration? In webpack/test.js or some karma.conf.js file

**Q2**: What is in this conf file?

**Q3**: Do I need to install karma-webpack?

---

#### EDIT 1

I was able to install karma, jasmine and es6 support, **BUT** *it's still not correctly integrated in the RoR ecosystem*

*/package.json*

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
    "standard": "^10.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
...
```

*/karma.conf.js*

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: 'app/javascript/',

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    files: [
      { pattern: 'test/*.spec.js', watched: false },
      { pattern: 'test/**/*.spec.js', watched: false }
    ],

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    preprocessors: {
      'test/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
      'test/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
    },

    webpack: {
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      },
      watch: true
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  })
}
```

*/app/javascript/test/my_test.spec.js*

```
describe("A suite", () => {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

> $ karma start

```
25 09 2017 15:45:02.199:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/javascript/test/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
25 09 2017 15:45:02.217:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/javascript/test/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
25 09 2017 15:45:03.147:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://0.0.0.0:8080/
25 09 2017 15:45:03.156:WARN [karma]: Port 8080 in use
25 09 2017 15:45:03.156:WARN [karma]: Port 8081 in use
25 09 2017 15:45:03.157:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:8082/
25 09 2017 15:45:03.157:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
25 09 2017 15:45:03.173:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
25 09 2017 15:45:03.310:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag

25 09 2017 15:45:03.837:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 1lM4B1iRIygqSYz3AAAA with id 19034471
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.043 secs / 0.001 secs)
```

**Q1**: Where do I do the configuration? In webpack/test.js or some karma.conf.js file

**A1**: karma.conf.js is working, but I don't think my approach is best

**Q2**: What is in this conf file?

**A2**: Still not sure

**Q3**: Do I need to install karma-webpack?

**A3**: Yes, I think so

---

**Q4**: What do I have to change to do the following (in RoR 5.1.x)?

From: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html

*/app/javascript/test/components/my_component.spec.js*

```
// Import Vue and the component being tested
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from 'path/to/MyComponent.vue'

// Here are some Jasmine 2.0 tests, though you can
// use any test runner / assertion library combo you prefer
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  // Inspect the raw component options
  it('has a created hook', () => {
    expect(typeof MyComponent.created).toBe('function')
  })
  
  // Evaluate the results of functions in
  // the raw component options
  it('sets the correct default data', () => {
    expect(typeof MyComponent.data).toBe('function')
    const defaultData = MyComponent.data()
    expect(defaultData.message).toBe('hello!')
  })
  
  // Inspect the component instance on mount
  it('correctly sets the message when created', () => {
    const vm = new Vue(MyComponent).$mount()
    expect(vm.message).toBe('bye!')
  })
  
  // Mount an instance and inspect the render output
  it('renders the correct message', () => {
    const Ctor = Vue.extend(MyComponent)
    const vm = new Ctor().$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.textContent).toBe('bye!')
  })
})
```

Comment: If you do not mix rails and vue.js, that means that you should have 2 separate applications - Rails serving an API and a Vue.js app using that API and delivering content. And since all of your questions are vue related, i suggest you remove rails tag, not to confuse people. As for the answers - Unfortunately I cannot help with Karma. I use Vue.js and Rails through webpack served in one App, thus I also test everyhting through feature tests (capybara)

Comment: It's more of a set up issue; it's about "rails/webpacker" and the set up of karma testing within "Ruby on Rails 5.x" --> related RoR file: "/config/webpack/test.js"

Comment: .. take a look at gitlab's source code - it uses rails as backend and vue as frontend. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq. Might help you in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'd used a custom Webpack configurations in Karma earlier but that's just redundant Webpack and preprocessors logic I had. So I came up with this approach which seems correct to me.

I would recommend this: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/testing.md#karma-setup-for-typescript

P.S. I'm intentionally not copy-pasting the code snippets since the existing doc may change in future.

Comment: Thank you! I will test it in the week ahead and give you the bounty if it's successful